# I need to create file with name is the result of the command in Solaris

Tags: shell, files, command-substitution

I need to create only one file with name is the result of the command `ls -l | head -2`.
I can't use environment variables. The filename must contain newline symbols.

I've tried to use `touch 'ls -l | head -2'`, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: What shell are you using? In most shells, you want to do `touch $(ls -l | head -2)` or `touch \`ls -l | head -2\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the output of that command directly as the input of touch:

```
touch "$(ls -l | head -2)"
```

The quotes are important, as there are bound to be spaces and a newline in the output of the `ls -l | head -2` part.